# Hadoop DataStreamer Exception: File could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1)

Tags: hadoop

I tried to load json data from my local into hadoop hdfs, I use these commands, and it throwing exception:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal path/files/file.json input/
hadoop fs -put path/files/file.json input/
```

I've check using `jps` command, found out that hadoop is running.

```
26039 ResourceManager
30858 SecondaryNameNode
35605 Jps
26147 NodeManager
30714 DataNode
```

This is detail of the exception:

```
WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File path/files/file.json._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget(BlockManager.java:1471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:526)
copyFromLocal: File path/files/file.json._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

How should I do? I need the data to be loaded into hdfs. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you check datanode log. you may find reason for this issue.

Comment: Where is you NameNode ? Start it up.

Comment: @GauravMishra ok, I'll check the log

Comment: @user2018791 namenode wont start even I restart it (stop-dfs.sh && start-dfs.sh). in jps, I see secondary namenode started.

Comment: @Noval Agung Prayogo Check the log to see why NN can't be started. There maybe some configuration issues.

Answer (score 3):

This recently happened to me and it was because the HDFS utilization was close to 100%. You can check your usage by running:

```
hdfs dfs -df -h
```

Increasing the HDFS size by increasing the number of cluster nodes solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check jps, you need 6 process after start-all.sh. Here you start fail NameNode process.

please format NameNode:

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

Comment: Sometime i had to delete datanode and namenode folder before format namenode.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the hard disk mentioned in  `hdfs-site.xml` was overfilled with files and Hadoop couldn't just create even minor files for locks.

Answer (score 0):

Config in master node or namenode:
--> /etc/hosts:

```
masterIP masterNodeName
slave1IP slave1Name
slave2IP slave2Name
```

Data-node should know master node to connect with.
You should define in each data node in /etc/hosts this:

```
node_IP masterNodeName
```

Or you could easily copy master's etc/hosts config to slave nodes using scp from master node.

```
scp /etc/hosts hadoopUser@slaveiName:/etc/hosts
```

Master Node must be able to connect with slaves through ssh without passwords.
Finally, you should have this config in core-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://masterNodeName:9000</value>
</property>
```